# Put continuous (uploaded) contents in multiple pages (divs)

Tags: javascript, css, html

My task is to generate a reader, which separate the uploaded HTML file into multiple pages like Microsoft Word. However, I don't know how to detect when the content reaches the bottom of the “papers”.

The uploaded file is a report which consist of multiple tables so its size is unpredictable. Styles of tables should be kept since the attributes should be represented in the new pages.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/7RCr5/) with my current code.

```
<div class="paper"> <span>
    Singing is the act of producing musical sounds with the voice, and augments regular speech by the use of both tonality and rhythm.<br /> One who sings is called a singer or vocalist. Singers perform music (Arias, Recitatives, Songs, etc.) that can be sung either with or without accompaniment by musical instruments. <br />Singing is often done in a group of other musicians, such as in a choir of singers with different voice ranges, or in an ensemble with instrumentalists, such as a rock group or baroque ensemble.   <br />
</span>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">ce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>brbr</td>
        <td>brbr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>brbr</td>
        <td>brbr</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span>       
   Singing is the act of producing musical sounds with the voice, and augments regular speech by the use of both tonality and rhythm.<br /> One who sings is called a singer or vocalist. Singers perform music (Arias, Recitatives, Songs, etc.) that can be sung either with or without accompaniment by musical instruments. <br />Singing is often done in a group of other musicians, such as in a choir of singers with different voice ranges, or in an ensemble with instrumentalists, such as a rock group or baroque ensemble.
</span>
</div>

.paper {
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #DDD;
}
.table {
    width:100%;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Could you please tell me how to realize it?

Comment: [There is a reason why they do not allow you to submit the post with only a jsFiddle link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need for tags in titles, the tag system is there for a reason. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not been tested with content including HTML tags with various style, and I am not sure how efficient this is. Nonetheless here is a simple version:

http://jsfiddle.net/7RCr5/5/

```
#CSS
.page{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid rgb(222, 80, 80);
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```
#Javascript
window.onload = function()
{
    var text      = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
        textarr   = [],
        arrlen    = 0,
        pageno    = 1,
        page      = document.getElementById('page' + pageno),
        maxheight = page.offsetHeight;

    text += " " + text + " " + text; //<-- Test purposes
    textarr = text.split(" ");
    arrlen  = textarr.length;


    for(var i = 0; i < arrlen; ++i)
    {
        page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML + textarr[i] + " ";
        page.style.overflow = 'auto';

        if(page.scrollHeight > maxheight)
        {
            page.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML.substr(0, page.innerHTML.length - (textarr[i].length + 1));

            var parent = page.parentNode; 

            page = page.cloneNode(false);
            page.id = 'page' + ++pageno;
            page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML + textarr[i] + " ";

            parent.appendChild(page); 
        }

        else page.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
};
```

```
#HTML
<div id="pages">

    <div class="page" id="page1"></div>

</div>
```

I hope it's somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Since the input is unpredictable, the number of pages is unpredictable as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated the solution to make things a bit more dynamic. (fiddle updated as well)

Comment: That's awesome! I applied my styles in my project and performs well for pure text contents. However, a large proportion of my source consist of tables with simple themes, it seems not working. The table can refer to my previous fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/7RCr5/   .Sorry for disturbing.